# Typescript support - Intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-idea

Atom has a good support for typescript - able to navigation and help was good.

Do we have any good intellij plugin for intellij community edition which supports typescript?

Thanks

Comment: None so far. IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate is your choice if you want to work with TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response